# docker-compose: map an entire directory under the container without changing destination path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I can mount a directory under a container in docker-compose.yml like this:

```
volumes:    
  - ${SRC_PATH}:/usr/local/airflow/src/
```

My SRC_PATH is a path to a directory on the host. My issue is that the default behavior puts the content under my SRC_PATH to `/usr/local/airflow/src/`. However, what I want is to put the directory itself under destination path. So if my SRC_PATH is defined in .env file to be `/Users/myname/dev/abc` then I would like the path on container to be `/usr/local/airflow/src/abc`

The constraint is that I cannot hard-code the destination path in the compose file. The SRC_PATH will change in the .env file and I would like the destination path to change accordingly. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to take the `basename` of `$SRC_PATH` and append it to the folder in the container.

Ideally, it would be nice if you could do something like this:

```yaml
volumes:    
  - ${SRC_PATH}:/app/$(basename $SRC_PATH)
```

but, obviously, this does not work.

As far as I can tell, you have two easy options:

If the parent of `$SRC_PATH` is fixed and never changes, you can do this:

```yaml
volumes:    
  - /usr/local/whatever/${APP}:/app/${APP}
```

If it is not fixed, then I would consider defining `$DEST_PATH` as well:

```yaml
volumes:    
  - ${SRC_PATH}:/app/${DEST_PATH}
```

Comment: thanks. The easy options were what I though of but not ideal for my case. The ideal is what I wanted haha